# Is application developed by Adobe Flash Professional CS5 (not CS5.5) visible in App Store on iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, flash, adobe, app-store, flash-cs5

I just finished with developing my application by Adobe Flash Professional CS5 and I wonder if this will be visible to iPhones 4 because support for Retina displays was added since CS5.5.

There is section in my info.plist:

```
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <string>1</string>
    </array>
```

Is it enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not request high display resolution, retina display iPhones will render as previous generations (320x480).

If you add <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution> you will target iPhone 4 retina (640x960).

For example, to target both iPhone and iPad requesting high resolution:

```
    <iPhone>
        <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <string>1</string>
                <string>2</string>
            </array>
        ]]></InfoAdditions>
        <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
    </iPhone>
```